# How can I force tomEE to use mojarra?

Tags: jsf, tomcat, mojarra, apache-tomee

Is there any good way to ask TomEE to use mojarra instead of myfaces? I have tried to add the following in my pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
<version>${mojarra-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
<artifactId>tomee-mojarra</artifactId>
<version>1.6.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

However, I still get the following error when start TomEE.

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory. 
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:1135)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:379)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5493)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Jul 22, 2014 6:30:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /war.upms.online threw load() exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory     javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory. 
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:1135)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:379)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5493)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have checked and confirmed that the javax.faces-2.2.6.jar is in the WEB-INF/lib of my deployed war.

My application can started if I remove the above mojarra dependency from pom.xml and use the following instead.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
<artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
<version>${myfaces-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
<artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
<version>${myfaces-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to upgrade to the new tomee 1.7.0 PLUME, which is using mojarra.

However, you can try to switch libraries and see if it works, they use javax.faces.xxx.jar for mojarra and an adapter, which is tomee-mojarra-1.7.0.jar (and you have to remove tomee-myfaces.jar)